# Ruby SQLite3 OCRA executable missing sqlite_native.so

Tags: ruby, sqlite3-ruby, ocra

I am trying to package the following ruby script with OCRA (I am on Windows 10, Ruby 2.6):

```rb
require 'sqlite3'

puts SQLite3::VERSION
```

Running this in cmd works properly:

```
C:\Users\monday\Documents\projects\sqlite3_test>script.rb
1.4.2
```

When I package `script.rb`  the following way:

```
ocra --gem-full=sqlite3 --dll sqlite3.dll script.rb --output script.exe --verbose
```

I have added `sqlite3.dll` and `sqlite3.def` to my `PATH` and into `C:\Ruby26-x64\bin` as per various suggestions on SO and GitHub.

Here is the error that pops up when I run the resulting `script.exe`:

```
C:\Users\monday\Documents\projects\sqlite3_test>script.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from C:/Users/monday/AppData/Local/Temp/ocr7747.tmp/src/script.rb:1:in `<main>'
        1: from C:/Users/monday/AppData/Local/Temp/ocr7747.tmp/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
C:/Users/monday/AppData/Local/Temp/ocr7747.tmp/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- sqlite3 (LoadError)
        6: from C:/Users/monday/AppData/Local/Temp/ocr7747.tmp/src/script.rb:1:in `<main>'
        5: from C:/Users/monday/AppData/Local/Temp/ocr7747.tmp/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:34:in `require'
        4: from C:/Users/monday/AppData/Local/Temp/ocr7747.tmp/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:130:in `rescue in require'
        3: from C:/Users/monday/AppData/Local/Temp/ocr7747.tmp/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:130:in `require'
        2: from C:/Users/monday/AppData/Local/Temp/ocr7747.tmp/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/lib/sqlite3.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        1: from C:/Users/monday/AppData/Local/Temp/ocr7747.tmp/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
C:/Users/monday/AppData/Local/Temp/ocr7747.tmp/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- sqlite3/2.6/sqlite3_native (LoadError)
        7: from C:/Users/monday/AppData/Local/Temp/ocr7747.tmp/src/script.rb:1:in `<main>'
        6: from C:/Users/monday/AppData/Local/Temp/ocr7747.tmp/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:34:in `require'
        5: from C:/Users/monday/AppData/Local/Temp/ocr7747.tmp/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:130:in `rescue in require'
        4: from C:/Users/monday/AppData/Local/Temp/ocr7747.tmp/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:130:in `require'
        3: from C:/Users/monday/AppData/Local/Temp/ocr7747.tmp/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/lib/sqlite3.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        2: from C:/Users/monday/AppData/Local/Temp/ocr7747.tmp/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
        1: from C:/Users/monday/AppData/Local/Temp/ocr7747.tmp/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
C:/Users/monday/AppData/Local/Temp/ocr7747.tmp/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': 126: The specified module could not be found.   - C:/Users/monday/AppData/Local/Temp/ocr7747.tmp/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.so (LoadError)
```

I am sure that `lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.so` is present in the temporary folder, judging by OCRA's output:

```
...
m lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/lib
a lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/lib/sqlite3.rb
m lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/lib/sqlite3
a lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/lib/sqlite3/constants.rb
a lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/lib/sqlite3/database.rb
a lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/lib/sqlite3/errors.rb
a lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/lib/sqlite3/pragmas.rb
a lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/lib/sqlite3/resultset.rb
a lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.so <<< HERE!
a lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb
a lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/lib/sqlite3/translator.rb
a lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/lib/sqlite3/value.rb
a lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/lib/sqlite3/version.rb
...
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research I found out that the error message `The specified module could not be found.` means that the program might be missing required DLLs. Now that `sqlite3_native.so` is present, I presumed that it *is* that program that is missing DLLs. Running `dumpbin` on it gave the following results:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community>dumpbin /dependents C:\Ruby26-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.6.0\gems\sqlite3-1.4.2\lib\sqlite3\sqlite3_native.so
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 14.22.27905.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file C:\Ruby26-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.6.0\gems\sqlite3-1.4.2\lib\sqlite3\sqlite3_native.so

File Type: DLL

  Image has the following dependencies:

    x64-msvcrt-ruby260.dll
    KERNEL32.dll
    msvcrt.dll
    libsqlite3-0.dll

...
```

Apparently, `libsqlite3-0.dll` was never detected by OCRA, and thus never moved into temporary folder's `bin/` directory. A quick search revealed that `libsqlite3-0.dll` is indeed present on my machine at `C:\Ruby26-x64\msys64\mingw64\bin`. I moved it to `C:\Ruby26-x64\bin`, and ran OCRA with the following options:

```
ocra --dll libsqlite3-0.dll script.rb --output script.exe
```

Later, I realized that OCRA is now able to detect this DLL on its own:

```
=== Adding ruby executable ruby.exe
=== Adding detected DLL C:/Ruby26-x64/bin/ruby_builtin_dlls/libgmp-10.dll
=== Adding detected DLL C:/Ruby26-x64/bin/ruby_builtin_dlls/libffi-6.dll
=== Adding detected DLL C:/Ruby26-x64/bin/libsqlite3-0.dll <<<< HERE!
=== Adding detected DLL C:/Ruby26-x64/bin/ruby_builtin_dlls/libgcc_s_seh-1.dll
=== Adding detected DLL C:/Ruby26-x64/bin/ruby_builtin_dlls/libwinpthread-1.dll
=== Adding detected DLL C:/Ruby26-x64/bin/ruby_builtin_dlls/zlib1.dll
=== Adding detected DLL C:/Ruby26-x64/bin/ruby_builtin_dlls/libssl-1_1-x64.dll
=== Adding detected DLL C:/Ruby26-x64/bin/ruby_builtin_dlls/libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll
=== Adding external manifest C:/Ruby26-x64/bin/ruby_builtin_dlls/ruby_builtin_dlls.manifest
```

So, finally:

```
ocra script.rb --output script.exe
```

Works properly, and there is no need for `sqlite3.dll`.

This seems to be quite a universal solution, as I was able to make puma run from within OCRA-packaged script by adding required DLLs to Ruby installation's `bin/` folder.